# Term for believing that no one believes in supernatural paranormal stuff

Tags: supernaturalism

There are terms like atheist and agnostic for deities for the person themself, but what if one not only doesn't believe in stuff that conflicts with their experienced observations, but believes that no one else believes it either? Like one could figure neuroscience will be able to prove it someday. Like if one believes that supernatural forces could stop a pen from dropping in the air, their brain would react in a way, thinking it's possible,  but neuroscience may show that that's not true, and that what people describe as beliefs are actually something different than knowing (honestly believing) that the pen will continue to fall if not acted upon by something natural. Especially if falling on them, which may cause a reflex action.

[Belief](https://www.wordnik.com/words/belief) is

> belief
> Definitions
> from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 5th Edition.
> -noun The mental act, condition, or habit of placing trust or confidence in another.
> -noun Mental acceptance of and conviction in the truth, actuality, or validity of something.
> -noun Something believed or accepted as true, especially a particular tenet or a body of tenets accepted by a group of persons.

So this person may argue that there should be more of a distinction between the 2nd and 3rd definitions, i.e. 'mental acceptance' that neuroscience may be able to objectively verify someday, and just 'acceptance'. Since it would seem the 3rd is riding on the coattails of the 2nd.

Comment: What people describe as beliefs cannot "actually" be something different because "belief" means whatever people agree to describe it as. And what neuroscience may prove some day is irrelevant to what words mean today. You'll have to better explain what your "honestly believing" is supposed to mean differently from the usual  "believing" to make this question intelligible.

Comment: It's a bit of an embellishment to claim the question is not intelligible, however, Conifold's point that, short of catching someone lying about what they believe, there is no scientific basis for claiming that a person who believes something doesn't believe the thing he or she believes. If you, as I do, reject supernaturalism, that doesn't mean that supernaturalism as a belief doesn't exist. It only means that supernatural explanation is be explained with more parsimony with naturalistic explanation.

Comment: skeptic.........

Comment: But "skeptic" is about one that "does not believe in supernatural paranormal stuff". What does it mean that one "believe that **no one** believes in supernatural paranormal stuff"? There are person that believe in supernatural...

Comment: This would be a subset of "Apologist for Dogmatic Physicalism".  There has been a strain of physicalist dogmatism that denies the validity of any rival POVs for a century.  This was, after all, the rationale for Behaviorism in both psychology and philosophy.

Comment: The verb "believe" means two quite different things: One, it means a sense that one *knows* something is true, and the other is just a sense that one *expects something is likely* to be true. Which meaning is used in the question (or is it a third meaning)?

Answer (score 0):

While atheism defines itself as a negative, as in the rejection in the belief of God, **one who is "anti-supernatural" is simple a [philosophical naturalist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturalism_(philosophy)) or believes in methodological naturalism as a way to truth.** [Natural epistemology (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/epistemology-naturalized/) is the marriage of naturalism with philosophical methods for finding the truth.

**Naturalists, bound by [empirical evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_evidence), will never believe that no one believes in supernaturalism, because it is patent that the majority of people do believe in supernaturalism.** Belief is an imaginative venture, and doesn't require empirical evidence at all. I can believe there is a [teapot in orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_teapot), for instance, and I do not require a shred of evidence for it. But I will never convince a skeptical empiricist without empirical evidence. It's fair to say that science actually makes the case that belief in the supernatural is the norm, and that it is an outgrowth of how we make sense of the world. It might seem ironic, but supernaturalism is quite a regular and natural phenomenon.

**Will psychology and philosophy explain why people believe in the supernatural? I think a case has already been made for it.** Consider [anthropomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropomorphism), for instance. Of course, those who believe in a naturalized epistemology and believe it accounts for strong, non-empirical belief of the supernatural believe in fundamentally different metaphysics than those who believe in the supernatural, though there is a substantial number of scientists and engineers who do subscribe to the supernatural and paranormal. Such scientists believe in ESP, remote viewing, nonhuman intelligences who communicate telepathically, and both obscure and mainstream religious belief.

**Ultimately, what is natural and supernatural tends to hinge on one's views of [empiricism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empiricism).** If one believes that one is talking to the Virgin Mary, despite the lack of physical explanation, one can simply claim that the sensory experience is too powerful not to consider empirical evidence. This leads to the rather sticky wicket of the difference between first and third-person reports. This sort of communion with the supernatural is not only personally evident, but sometimes as in the case of [Lourdes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lourdes_apparitions) or [Fatima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Our_Lady_of_F%C3%A1tima), is testified to by large groups of people many of whom are non-believers.

Comment: Btw, since belief is subjective, it's tough to claim that someone who claims to believe in the supernatural doesn't.